# notifyDataSetChanged() doesnt work for me

Tags: android, notifydatasetchanged

I'm trying to upfate ListView. 
In tab_3 i wonna tap on item and in tab 2 i wanna get query by this item. 
But when i swipe from tab 3 to tab 2 ListView in tab 2 is not updated. I understan that view for tab 2 creates before, but how can i update listview on tab 2 with tap on listvew in tab 3?

My source:

```
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(new SamplePagerAdapter());
    mSlidingTabLayout = (SlidingTabLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.sliding_tabs);
    mSlidingTabLayout.setViewPager(mViewPager);
}

class SamplePagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 3;
    }


    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object o) {
        return o == view;
    }

    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                View view0 = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.tab_1, container, false);
                Log.d(TAG, "Tab case 0");
                container.addView(view0);
                return view0;

            case 1:
                View view1 = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.tab_2, container, false);
                Log.d(TAG, "Tab case 1 ");
                ListView lvLibList = (ListView)view1.findViewById(R.id.lvLibList);
                Database database = new Database(getActivity());
                if (NAME != null) {
                    mNames = database.getListByName(NAME);

                } else {
                    mNames = database.getListByName(" ");
                }
                NameListAdapter namelistAdapter = new NameListAdapter(mMedias);
                lvNameList.setAdapter(namelistAdapter);
                namelistAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                container.addView(view1);
                return view1;
            default:
                View view2 = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.tab_3, container, false);
                Log.d(TAG, "Tab 3 ");
                ListView lvSourceList = (ListView)view2.findViewById(R.id.lvSourceList);
                Database mb = new Database(getActivity());
                mFull = mb.getFull();
                FullAdapter fullAdapter = new FullAdapter(mFull);
                lvFullList.setAdapter(fullAdapter);

                lvFullList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view1,
                                            int position, long id) {

                        Full f = (Full)parent.getAdapter().getItem(position);
                        NAME = f.getName(); 
                        Log.d(TAG, NAME);
                    }
                });
                container.addView(view2);
                return view2;
        }
    }
```

Comment: notifyDataSetChanged(); only works when changes in the size of list not in the record modification of existing list(no changes in size).

Comment: It doesn't look like you are changing any data. But you modify the data onClick, you should also notifyDataSetChanged in the same method.

Answer (score 0):

You should write it in the `setUserVisibleHint` method. Override it like this. Reload the adapter appropriately and call `notifyDataSetChanged`

```
  public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
    super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
    if (isVisibleToUser) {

    }
    else {

    }
  }
```

Comment: I don't understand how I can use it. Can u help, plz?